# Is there a way in Selenium to post a copy paste protected password field?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to build a program to automatically upload documents onto a site 1 by 1 as the website administers won't give me access to their database.

My first problem arose just from trying to log into the system.  I found that when I use,

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.send_keys("pycon")
```

it will copy paste "pycon" into the form.  The form however is copy-paste protected and will never let me input into the form field.

The other problem arises when I use my browser to remember my username/password.  When I run the script the fields are empty when it loads, so I can't submit(even if I implicitly tell it to wait 30 seconds for the browser to load).

Lastly, if I am already logged in the program will open a new window and ask for login/password again!

Is there anyway around any of this?

Is there a function to force selenium to type out each letter seperately?  Is there a way to add my firefox profile on startup to force the rememberance of my username/password?  Is there a way to have my webdriver open up another tab instead of a new window in firefox?

Any help would be appreciated!  I need to get this done by Friday, thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you are identifying the field correctly? I doubt the issue is due to the field being protected. `send_keys` is similar to a user input and is not same as copy paste.

Comment: Are you able to share the relevant html?  And the rest of the code you have tried?

Comment: I am a dummy!  I was using send_keys(Keys.ENTER) before my password was entered and it was erroring out.  I apologize thanks for the quick responses though!

Answer (score 0):

I am a dummy! I was using send_keys(Keys.ENTER) before my password was entered and it was erroring out. I apologize thanks for the quick responses though!